# Print stylesheet, one page prints and cuts off remaining text in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, sass

I am trying to make google chrome jump into the next page when printing page content when it's full tried it on athor browsers and Works perfectly

### Here is an example of what i am getting :

[Printing window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsUZM.jpg)

---

Html code :

```
<div class="content1" style="display: block;
width: auto;
height: auto;
overflow: visible;">
  <table style="display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="header-space">&nbsp;</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="width: 100%;">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="content" style="display: block;
          width: auto;
          height: auto;
          overflow: visible;">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div class="header">
    <br>
    <a [routerLink]="['login']" class="simple-text logo-normal">
      <img [src]="img_Holcim2" alt="Lafrage Holcim" style="width: 8%;">
    </a>

    <a [routerLink]="['login']" class="simple-text logo-normal">
      <img [src]="logo" alt="Lafrage Holcim" style="width: 6%; margin-left: 858px; margin-top: 1%;">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sass code :

```
.header, .header-space, .footer, .footer-space
  height: 100px

.header
  position: fixed
  width:100%
  top: 0

@media screen
  \:host
    display: none

.content1
  margin: 0
  height: 100%
  display: block
  width: auto
  height: auto
  overflow: visible
```

Any idiea how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding the `display: table` attribute